# Scrape a url in Python

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to get the adidas shoe [link](https://www.tennisexpress.com/search.cfm?searchKeyword=BB6892) from a search page, can't figure it out what I'm doing wrong.

**I tried** `tags = soup.find("section", {"class": "productList"}).findAll("a")`
Doesnt work :(

I also tried to print all `href` and the desired link is not in there :(

**So I'm expecting to print this :**

```
https://www.tennisexpress.com/adidas-mens-adizero-ubersonic-50-yrs-ltd-tennis-shoes-off-white-and-signal-blue-62138


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.tennisexpress.com/search.cfm?searchKeyword=BB6892"

# Getting the webpage, creating a Response object.
response = requests.get(url)

# Extracting the source code of the page.
data = response.text

# Passing the source code to BeautifulSoup to create a BeautifulSoup object for it.
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

# Extracting all the <a> tags into a list.
tags = soup.find("section", {"class": "productList"}).findAll("a")

# Extracting URLs from the attribute href in the <a> tags.
for tag in tags:
    print(tag.get('href'))
```

**Here's the html code for that link**

```
<section class="productList"> <article class="productListing"> <a class="product" href="//www.tennisexpress.com/adidas-mens-adizero-ubersonic-50-yrs-ltd-tennis-shoes-off-white-and-signal-blue-62138" title="Men`s Adizero Ubersonic 50 Yrs LTD Tennis Shoes Off White and Signal Blue" onmousedown="return nxt_repo.product_x('38698770','1');"> <span class="sale">SALE</span> <span class="image"> <img src="//www.tennisexpress.com/prodimages/78091-DEFAULT-m.jpg" alt="Men`s Adizero Ubersonic 50 Yrs LTD Tennis Shoes Off White and Signal Blue"> </span> <span class="brand"> Adidas </span> <span class="name"> Men`s Adizero Ubersonic 50 Yrs LTD Tennis Shoes Off White and Signal Blue </span> <span class="pricing"> <strong class="listPrice">$140.00</strong> <strong class="percentOff">0% OFF</strong> <strong class="salePrice">$139.95</strong> </span> <br> </a> </article> </section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By inspecting Network tab in Chrome DevTools you can notice that the products you search are fetched after making a request to `https://tennisexpress-com.ecomm-nav.com/search.js`. You can see example response [here](https://tennisexpress-com.ecomm-nav.com/search.js?initial_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tennisexpress.com%2Fsearch.cfm%3FsearchKeyword%3Dadidas&search_return=all&keywords=adidas&callback=jQuery33103156303818514996_1527592433524&_=1527592433525). As you can see, it's a mess, so I wouldn't follow this approach.

In your code, you couldn't see the products because the request is made by JavaScript (running in your browser) after the initial page load. Neither standalone [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) nor [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) can render that content. However you can do that with [`Requests-HTML`](https://html.python-requests.org/index.html) that has JavaScript support (it uses Chromium behind the scenes).

**Code:**

```
from itertools import chain
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
url = 'https://www.tennisexpress.com/search.cfm?searchKeyword=adidas+boost'
r = session.get(url)
r.html.render()

links = list(chain(*[prod.absolute_links for prod in r.html.find('.product')]))
```

I used [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to join all the sets with absolute links together and I created a list out of it.

```
>>> links
['https://www.tennisexpress.com/adidas-mens-barricade-2018-boost-tennis-shoes-black-and-night-metallic-62110',
 'https://www.tennisexpress.com/adidas-mens-barricade-2018-boost-tennis-shoes-white-and-matte-silver-62109',
 ...
 'https://www.tennisexpress.com/adidas-mens-supernova-glide-7-running-shoes-black-and-white-41636',
 'https://www.tennisexpress.com/adidas-womens-adizero-boston-6-running-shoes-solar-yellow-and-midnight-gray-45268']
```

Don't forget to install Requests-HTML with `pip install requests-html`.

Comment: your answer was really clearing a lot of things ! I tried to run your code an got an error : `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests_html`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention you need to install this package. I updated my answer.

Comment: hmmm....having issues to install `pip install requests-html` on mac siera 10.12.6 / using python 3.6   .... saying `Failed building wheel for websockets`

Comment: I guess you install packages globally and there are some conflicts. You can take a look at [`pipenv`](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv) to manage packages independently in each of your projects.

Comment: ohhh man...I got your code, and I can't install that requests_html thing....such a pain...I'm basicaly stuck....

Comment: alright @Jatimir, I got it to run on my machine, for some reasons it doesn't print anything. And I think it's running only in terminal, and not in the Sublime text though :( Do u have an idea ?

Comment: probably you forgot about `print()`

Comment: you are the Man ! Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")    
markup = soup.find_all("section", class_=["productList"])
markupContent = markup.get_text()
```

So your code goes like

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.tennisexpress.com/search.cfm?searchKeyword=BB6892"

r = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
productMarkup = soup.find_all("section", class_=["productList"])
product = productMarkup.get_text()
```

Comment: can I have the whole code ? Or at least guide me please where to feed it in my code above ? Thank you !

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: @PaulaThomas I did. No luck. Maybe I'm not feeding it corectly, that's why I asked for a full code, or a guide where to place it inside my code. Thank you Paula

Comment: @AnotherUser31 done...please check edited answer. However, i went through your URL. There is no <section> with class name "productList" in the markup of that URL. That can be another failure point for your code. Please read the page source and soup result markup again to find the tag - identifier combination of your interest.

Comment: @harshvardhan I get an error about urllib... i guess because I use Python 3.6 ? what should I change in order to run it ? Thank you

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html

Also, check the tag identifier as I mentioned.

Comment: @harshvardhan can we chat please so I can solve this one please ?

Comment: @AnotherUser31 I couldn't get it working either. I suspect the page uses AJAX or similar.

Comment: @PaulaThomas so it's basically not possible to scrape it ? or it requires something more complicated. Badly need to find out !

Comment: @AnotherUser31 If it does use AJAX then you need Selenium webdriver. But may I suggest you use a DOM inspector to check how the page works. The one in the WebDeveloper extension to chrome is good.

Comment: @PaulaThomas alright...I'm gonna wait maybe someone else come up with an idea how to crack this one...Thank you for your time !

Comment: @AnotherUser31 please first find out the relevant tag and class / id on the URL has contents of your interest.

Comment: @AnotherUser31 I'll be travelling for a couple of hours but after that I'll be able to help a bit.

Comment: @harshvardhan that is the trickiest part I believe, I tried almost all tags and classes visible out there...no id though...

Comment: @PaulaThomas alright ! can't wait ! safe traveling ! get back to us asap health and happy and ready to find a solution for this issue

Comment: @AnotherUser31 oK back from standing on a train for 45 mins!

Comment: @PaulaThomas 45 ! standing ! noooo !!! Can you check my answer to your solution, please ?

Answer (score 0):

Right here's the solution:

```
import requests
import bs4.BeautifulSoup as bs
url="https://www.tennisexpress.com/mens-adidas-tennis-shoes"
req = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(req.text,'lxml') # lxml because page is more xml than html
arts = soup.findAll("a",class_="product")
```

and that gives you a list of links to all the adidas tennis shoes! I'm sure you can manage from there.

Comment: so you're saying I can't get the shoe from that search page ? because for me would be easier to find the products that I only need, instead of going and trying to look for the one I need. I'm sure we can figure out something. I'll be back in 30 minutes, maybe we can chat. No idea how to start a chat room though. Please help me with this.

Comment: I can't get it to give me a list of shoes :(  confused

Comment: Just do `links = [art['href'] for art in arts]` to get a "list of shoes", but still that solution doesn't answer your question and does a completely different thing.